# Pandas: Create binary columns (dummy/one-hot encode table) based on string column of predefined categories

Tags: python, pandas

I've been having a bit of trouble with this problem. I have a data frame of clothing items which have an associated description as below:

```
Item Description
R2G1 RED, BLUE, SHIRT
G23A YELLOW SHIRT
P001 BLUE, PINK SKIRT
```

I also have a list of items that contain the possible categories of the clothing items, ie.

```
categories = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'PINK', 'SHIRT', 'SKIRT']
```

I need to check the description fields of each item to see if they contain any of the strings in the categories list, and assign them the correct binary values in new columns based on the categories. The final output should look like this:

```
Item Description      Red Blue Yellow Pink Shirt Skirt
R2G1 RED, BLUE, SHIRT 1   1    0      0    1     0
G23A YELLOW SHIRT     0   0    1      0    1     0
P001 BLUE, PINK SKIRT 0   1    0      1    0     1
```

I've tried to use this function but I keep getting the AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper' error when I try to use it as follows:

```
def get_category(series):
    res = []
    for i in category_list:
        if i in series.upper():
            res.append(i)
    return res

df['Categories'] = df['Description'].apply(get_model)
df = df.join(df['Model'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

categories = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'PINK', 'SHIRT', 'SKIRT']

def categorize(df, categories):
    for category in categories:
        df[category] = np.where(df.Description.str.contains(category), 1, 0)
    return df 

df = categorize(df, categories)
```

**Output:**

| Item | Description | Red | Blue | Yellow | Pink | Shirt | Skirt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R2G1 | RED, BLUE, SHIRT | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| G23A | YELLOW SHIRT | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| P001 | BLUE, PINK SKIRT | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

If you make the items have a uniform separator, you can use the `sep` parameter of [`pd.Series.st.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to get out the one-hot encoding.  I do this by replacing the spaces with commas:

```
>>> df['Description'].str.replace(' ', ',').str.get_dummies(sep=',')
   BLUE  PINK  RED  SHIRT  SKIRT  YELLOW
0     1     0    1      1      0       0
1     0     0    0      1      0       1
2     1     1    0      0      1       0
```

Then you just need to join:

```
>>> df.join(df['Description'].str.replace(' ', ',').str.get_dummies(sep=','))
   Item       Description  BLUE  PINK  RED  SHIRT  SKIRT  YELLOW
0  R2G1  RED, BLUE, SHIRT     1     0    1      1      0       0
1  G23A      YELLOW SHIRT     0     0    0      1      0       1
2  P001  BLUE, PINK SKIRT     1     1    0      0      1       0
```

Important to note though (as commented by Rob), is that this is determining the categories from the `Description` column, rather than from the `categories` list itself.  So if you have descriptions that are not in `categories`, you would have extra columns.  E.g. if one description included `"GREEN"`, you would get a whole column for GREEN.

Similarly, categories not present in the descriptions would not be included as columns.  So if say the first row was missing, there would be no column for RED.

I can think of ways to fix those behaviors if that is an issue, but I think simpler would be to just go with [heretolearn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874573/13386979) or one of the others that explicitly incorporates `categories`.

Comment: upvoted - one point doesn't actually test against `categories` so if there are additional items in **Description** column they will turn up as columns

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `findall` and `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
```

---

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
f = df['Description'].str.findall('|'.join(categories))
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(f),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index))
```

---

A slower but simpler version of above `series.str.get_dummies` after `findall` only after joining them:

```
out = df.join(df['Description'].str.findall('|'.join(categories))
                         .str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

---

```
print(out)



   Item       Description  BLUE  PINK  RED  SHIRT  SKIRT  YELLOW
0  R2G1  RED, BLUE, SHIRT     1     0    1      1      0       0
1  G23A      YELLOW SHIRT     0     0    0      1      0       1
2  P001  BLUE, PINK SKIRT     1     1    0      0      1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the dummy table with [`str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html).  Then, to confine the columns to use only the predefined categories, we use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df_dum = (df['Description'].str.replace(r',?\s+', '|', regex=True)
                           .str.get_dummies()
                           .reindex(categories, fill_value=0, axis=1)
         )
```

Optionally, if you want to change the final column labels from all capital letters to title case strings, you can take the following extra step:

```
df_dum.columns = df_dum.columns.str.title()
```

Finally, join back with the original dataframe:

```
df.join(df_dum)
```

**Result:**

```
   Item       Description  Red  Blue  Yellow  Pink  Shirt  Skirt
0  R2G1  RED, BLUE, SHIRT    1     1       0     0      1      0
1  G23A      YELLOW SHIRT    0     0       1     0      1      0
2  P001  BLUE, PINK SKIRT    0     1       0     1      0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the list, use `pandas.get_dummies`, and take the max grouped by "Item":

```
df['vals'] = df['Description'].str.split('[,\s]+')
df2 = df.explode('vals')
(pd.concat([df2[['Item', 'Description']],
            pd.get_dummies(df2['vals'])
           ], axis=1)
   .groupby('Item', as_index=False)
   .max()
)
```

or, shorter alternative:

```
(pd.concat([df,
            (pd.get_dummies(df['Description'].str.split('[,\s]+').explode())
               .groupby(level=0).max())
           ], axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   Item       Description  BLUE  PINK  RED  SHIRT  SKIRT  YELLOW
0  G23A      YELLOW SHIRT     0     0    0      1      0       1
1  P001  BLUE, PINK SKIRT     1     1    0      0      1       0
2  R2G1  RED, BLUE, SHIRT     1     0    1      1      0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

- simple case of checking for each category item in the tokenised string
- `join()` result of this back to dataframe to get your required output

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['R2G1', 'G23A', 'P001'],
 'Description': ['RED, BLUE, SHIRT', 'YELLOW SHIRT', 'BLUE, PINK SKIRT']})

categories = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW', 'PINK', 'SHIRT', 'SKIRT']

df.join(df["Description"].apply(lambda s: pd.Series({c:c in re.split("[\, ]", s) for c in categories})).astype(int))
```

|  | Item | Description | RED | BLUE | YELLOW | PINK | SHIRT | SKIRT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | R2G1 | RED, BLUE, SHIRT | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | G23A | YELLOW SHIRT | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | P001 | BLUE, PINK SKIRT | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: This will, however, be much slower than the current other solutions on large dataframes (quick test, ~30 times slower on 30k rows) ;)

Comment: yup as `re.split("[\, ]", s)` is repeated 6 times